# Authenticate user by access token/ base auth on any handler

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'd like users to be able to access a RESTful server and be authenticated with an access token in the query string. For example `https://api.example.com/v1.0/articles?access_token=1234`

I have defined in the `models` file:

```
AccessToken
    created UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIME
    userId UserId
    token Text
    UniqueUserId userId
    UniqueToken token
    deriving Eq
    deriving Show
```

Every time a user is created, we'll assign them a unique token.

The question is how to do the authentication on the fly for every handler. So for example I would have an `ArticlesR` handler that should be allowed access only after the user has been authenticated (and thus also authorized).

There should not be a cookie involved. Every request will re-auth the user. Like this we could have a completely decoupled server that can serve any arbitrary domain.

Same question can also be asked about base auth. The gist is: How to authenticate from inside a *regular* handler

Comment: I see a reference to my use case in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.2.4/docs/src/Yesod-Auth.html#maybeAuthId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in implementing `maybeAuthId`

```
import Database.Persist.Sql (toSqlKey)

instance YesodAuth App where

maybeAuthId = do
    mToken <- lookupGetParam "access_token"
    case mToken of
        Nothing -> return Nothing
        Just token -> do
            mUser <- runDB $ selectFirst [AccessTokenToken ==. token] []
            case mUser of
                Nothing -> return Nothing
                Just user -> return $ Just . accessTokenUserId $ entityVal user
```

The above example will authenticate user ID by the access token passed in the query string. It assumes you have the following in your `models`:

```
AccessToken
    created UTCTime default=CURRENT_TIME
    userId UserId
    token Text
    UniqueUserId userId
    UniqueToken token
    deriving Eq
    deriving Show
```